# How to correctly use includes to solve N+1 rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading, nested-includes

I have 3 models:

1)ContentType (parent)

2)RecentTools (last 3 childs of ContentType, model is Tool, recent_tools is only association using scope of tool)

3)ToolTranslation (child of tool)

I want to solve my n+1, and write the includes for this. Right now im stucked:

```
ContentType.includes(recent_tools: :tool_translation)
```

This should work I guess accorting to guides, but this includes **always** returns me a full list of tools, instead of recent_tools, and all of the translations for them.

This is my tool.rb

```
class Tool < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :tool_translation, -> { where(locale: I18n.locale) }, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :content_type

  scope :recent, ->(number){ limit(number) }
end
```

And content_type model:

```
class ContentType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tools, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :recent_tools, -> { recent(3) }, class_name: "Tool"
end
```

Where I am missing? Can someone explain? Maybe its a bad logic to get a recent tools(it needed because I need only 3 last tools of content_type on main page)? How should I write the includes correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `has_many :recent_tools, -> { recent(3) }, class_name: "Tool"` to `has_many :recent_tools, -> { limit(3) }, class_name: "Tool"`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

`ContentType.includes(:recent_tools, recent_tools: :tool_translation)`

In case not, please let me know.

Comment: still returning me a full tools list(n+1 query fixed at all, but I need only last 3 tools, not all). Without includes it works fine. Also I noted that when I call
content_type.recent_tools.count in debugger mode it returned me 3 but if I do just content_type.recent_tools it shows me ALL of the tools.